# How do I update forked repository from master in bitbucket web interface?

Tags: bitbucket

I have created fork of some repository in bitbucket, which has later changed. Now I want to get these changes to my new repository. How do I do it through bitbucket web interface?

I've spend significant time trying to follow bitbucket documentation, but it is outdated. I don't have mentioned Settings->Fork in the interface.

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Where-is-the-fork-sync-feature/qaq-p/786862

Comment: How can this help me? People in commends complain that the option has gone from the interface. Docs on bitbucket are inadequate.

Comment: The question was "How do I do it through bitbucket web interface?" The discussion is about exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually synchronize your branch at any time using Synchronize by going to the Settings > Fork syncing tab for the forked repository, or on either of the Source or Commits tabs for a repository.

Please see the following link for more info: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/keeping-forks-synchronized-776639961.html

Alternatly, under repository details the following button should be available [image]

Comment: I don't have Settings -> Fork. Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: Added a second way of doing it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found it, it is missing in the documentation at all:

first you should access panel **Repository Details** on the right, you might need to click icon on the right:

[image]

and then click the grey button.

Comment: And that was in the discussion I linked you to. "See Repository details tab on right corner up, go through line by line . You will find there what we are looking for..!"